# Is there any way to validate if input is passed in REGO language?

Tags: opa, rego

In REGO language how can we validate if an input exists?
I got one way to do this.

```
package play

default hello = false

hello {
    input.message
}
```

But is this the right approach? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is the right way. In the rare case where you'll need to account for the possibility of `input.message` being set, but be assigned the value `false`, you could use [unification](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#unification-) to check for that:

```
package play

hello {
    _ = input.message
}
```

But 99% of the times, your solution is what I'd go with.

Answer (score 0):

package play

default inputcheck = false

inputcheck {input["message"]}

This returns true if the key 'message' exist in your input . Else it returns default false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).